# Execution of Assigning value and Logical AND and Ternary operator

Tags: javascript, conditional-operator, operator-precedence

I am learning JavaScript, and I do not understand what is the execution sequence of 2nd line. Please advise!

```
let envArr;
const envName = envArr && envArr[0] ? envArr[0] : "env1";
```

Comment: What is unclear here? If it's `(envArr && envArr[0]) ? envArr[0] : "env1"` or `envArr && (envArr[0] ? envArr[0] : "env1")`? You can easily test that yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here output of `envArr && envArr[0]` would be considered for execution of ternary operator.

On other hand doing something like this (it's illogical, but just for sake of example) -

```
envArr && (envArr[0] ? envArr[0] : "env1");
```

Will execute ternary operation based on solely `envArr[0]` and it's output will be anded with `envArr`, simplified version will look like this.

```
envArr && output_of_ternary
```

BTW better way of doing above check from your question will be like this -

```
const envName = envArr?.[0] || 'env1'
```

We are using optional chaining, you can find more details about optional chaining [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)